# When using notifyItemInserted the onBindViewHolder keeps the position where the item was inserted

Tags: android, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

When I add a new item, using following line of code: -

```
proAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

The onBindViewHolder maintains the position 0.

Which is a problem when using the onClick listener because it will always be at position 0

So if I click on and try to delete the 5th item the item at position 0 will always get deleted.

Is there a way to reset the onBindViewHolder position?

When I am using following, then there is no issue: -

```
proAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my code when adding a new item in the Java class

```
        setPro.addToSpinnerItems(0, newItem);

        //proAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        proAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(0);
        layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
```

Here is my code for the onclicklistener

```
        holder.myImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        spinnerItems.remove(position);
        Log.d("myTag", "Delete item: " + position);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); //Here I could also use notifyItemRemoved
    });
```

Comment: have you changed the adapter data list before to do notifyItemInserted ?

Comment: It should **not** delete the `0 th` if `5 th` item is clicked. There is some other issue , which needs to be debugged !

Comment: Can you provied related code that you call "notifyIteminserted" and change your data list

Comment: Show how you setup `onClickListener`. I'm guessing you're holding hard reference to `position` passed to `onBindViewHolder` instead of using `getAdapterPosition()` to obtain current position.

Comment: After deleting the first item all the items delete at their correct position. It's only on the first click

Comment: I have edited my question and added the code where I add a new item to the RecyclerView Adapter

Comment: it's as I though. modify your listener to use `holder.adapterPosition` instead of `position` and it should work.

Comment: @Pawel thanks, works perfectly.
I did not know you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the position of viewHolder using `getAdapterPosition()` instead of saving it in a variable, change your code to something like this

```
    holder.myImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    spinnerItems.remove(position);
    Log.d("myTag", "Delete item: " + position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position); 
});
```